# How do i find a specific li with the data attriibute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

jQuery

```
$('.left_ul').find('li')
```

this will return all the li's but i need to find the li with the data="something"

```
<li>Not me</li>
<li>Not me</li>
<li>Not me</li>
<li>Not me</li>
<li>Not me</li>
<li data='something'>I want this one</li>
<li>Not me</li>
```

Is there a way to do this easily

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.left_ul').find('li[data="something"]')
```

Comment: or just `$('.left_ul').find('li[data]')` if you don't know the value is `"something"`

Comment: or if you don't know what the `something` is you can do `.find('li[data]')` of course this will return all `li` in the `ul` that have that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.left_ul').find('li[data=something]');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[data=something]')
```

That should work :). It does for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.left_ul').find('li[data=something]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this for example:

```
$('.left_ul').find('li[data=something]');
```